# Importing CSV cant split correctly

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am importing a csv to excel, the csv file looks like this if i open it up in notepad:

"Name",”id”,”comment”,”date””Mike”,”123”,”NA------save notes above this line------“,”01/03/2018””Jane”,”278”,”ANS----save notes above this line”,”01/02/2017”

Now if i open it in word and check where the breaks are, they appear at the end of each line correctly but there are also breaks in the comment field and if i load the whole file into an array called whole_file and then split like this:

```
 lines = Split(whole_file, vbCrLf)
```

it will split correctly on the first line as these are the headers but on the following lines it will split at the carriages in the comments which i don't want it to do. If i remove chr(13) & chr(10) then the above split will not work. My question is what can i do to prepare my CSV so these carriages are removed from the comments or is there a way split each line say at the quotation marks which do not have a apostrophe in between?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to check the CSV, use Notepad++ or even better, a HexEdit app.

Comment: **You need unique line separator, which isn't used inside values.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in wizard to clarify the breaks in your data. Like comma, space, tab etc.